# apt-get update says E: Sub-process returned an error code

Tags: apt

I am getting this error whenever I try and run any apt-get command. Currently I am trying to run `sudo apt-get update`. I have also noticed that the `/var/lib/apt/lists` is empty.

How can I repopulate this directory with the needed files that show the installed applications? Is there a boot repair CD I can use or something to fix this?

I get the following error when I try to run `apt-get update`,

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for preston: 
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I am using Ubuntu 13.10

After running the command that @muru posted below this is the output:

```
$ sudo strace apt-get update
[sudo] password for preston: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for preston: 
execve("/usr/bin/apt-get", ["apt-get", "update"], [/* 14 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x245e000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971c90000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=47071, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 47071, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5971c84000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\24\3\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1287048, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3383888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5971735000
mprotect(0x7f597186a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5971a6a000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x135000) = 0x7f5971a6a000
mmap(0x7f5971a6f000, 592, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971a6f000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\265\5\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=979056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3159072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5971431000
mprotect(0x7f5971517000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5971716000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe5000) = 0x7f5971716000
mmap(0x7f5971720000, 82976, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971720000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88408, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971c83000
mmap(NULL, 2184224, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f597121b000
mprotect(0x7f5971230000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f597142f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7f597142f000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\36\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1853400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3961912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5970e53000
mprotect(0x7f5971010000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5971210000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7f5971210000
mmap(0x7f5971216000, 17464, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971216000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\17\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10680, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105624, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5970c50000
mprotect(0x7f5970c52000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5970e51000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f5970e51000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971c82000
mmap(NULL, 2109736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5970a4c000
mprotect(0x7f5970a4f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5970c4e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f5970c4e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\36\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=100728, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2195784, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5970833000
mprotect(0x7f597084b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5970a4a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f5970a4a000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\23\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=66600, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2161864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f5970623000
mprotect(0x7f5970632000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5970831000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe000) = 0x7f5970831000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0T\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1063328, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971c81000
mmap(NULL, 3158344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f597031f000
mprotect(0x7f5970422000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f5970621000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x102000) = 0x7f5970621000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971c80000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971c7e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f5971c7e740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5971210000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5970621000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5970831000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5970a4a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5970c4e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5970e51000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f597142f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971c7d000
mprotect(0x7f5971716000, 32768, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f5971a6a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x632000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f5971c92000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f5971c84000, 47071)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x245e000
brk(0x247f000)                          = 0x247f000
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1607664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1607664, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7f5971af4000
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/var/lib/apt/.", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26258, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26258, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 4, 0) = 0x7f5971c89000
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 17 entries */, 32768)    = 592
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00CDMountPoint", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Acquire::cdrom {\n  mount \"/media"..., 8191) = 82
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Aptitude::Get-Root-Command \"sudo"..., 8191) = 49
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00trustcdrom", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "APT::Authentication::TrustCDROM "..., 8191) = 40
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "APT\n{\n  NeverAutoRemove\n  {\n\t\"^f"..., 8191) = 350
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "// File autogenerated by /etc/ke"..., 8191) = 642
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/05aptitude", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "aptitude::Keep-Unused-Pattern \"^"..., 8191) = 157
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Li"..., 8191) = 129
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success"..., 8191) = 108
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-show-versions", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "// When Apt's cache is updated ("..., 8191) = 164
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "APT::Archives::MaxAge \"30\";\nAPT:"..., 8191) = 85
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Li"..., 8191) = 80
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20changelog", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "// Server information for apt-ch"..., 8191) = 123
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "// Automatically upgrade package"..., 8191) = 2138
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "// Pre-configure all packages wi"..., 8191) = 182
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99update-notifier", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "DPkg::Post-Invoke {\"if [ -d /var"..., 8191) = 231
read(4, "", 8191)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/etc/apt/apt.conf", 0x7fff8619bb50) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/dpkg/status", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1252691, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/dpkg", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=257632, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/debian_version", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=11, ...}) = 0
stat("", 0x7fff8619bbd0)                = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getuid()                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f5970e89ff0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x409fd0, [WINCH], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f5970e89ff0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=54, ws_col=211, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
stat("/etc/apt/sources.list", 0x7fff8619b570) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/apt/sources.list.d/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/apt/sources.list.d/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/apt/sources.list.d/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/var/lib/apt/lists/lock", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_NOFOLLOW, 0640) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETLK, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5971c88000
)                     = 2
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt/lists/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
getcwd("/home/preston", 298)            = 14
chdir("/var/lib/apt/lists/")            = 0
getdents(5, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 104
getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(5)                                = 0
chdir("/home/preston/")                 = 0
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
getcwd("/home/preston", 298)            = 14
chdir("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/")    = 0
getdents(5, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(5)                                = 0
chdir("/home/preston/")                 = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5971c7ea10) = 11800
wait4(11800, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 100}], 0, NULL) = 11800
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=11800, si_status=100, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f5970e89ff0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f5970e89ff0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin", 0x7fff8619b510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin", 0x7fff8619b510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/cache/apt/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/cache/apt/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/cache/apt/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
stat("/var/cache/apt/archives", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=69632, ...}) = 0
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/var/cache/apt/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/cache/apt/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/cache/apt/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
getdents(4, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
stat("/var/cache/apt/archives", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=69632, ...}) = 0
getdents(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/var/lib/dpkg/lock", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_NOFOLLOW, 0640) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETLK, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/updates/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
getdents(5, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
write(2, "E", 1E)                        = 1
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "Sub-process returned an error co"..., 34Sub-process returned an error code) = 34
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(100)                         = ?
+++ exited with 100 +++
```

Comment: Okay I have edited the original notes.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? You should include that in the post or in the tags.

Comment: This [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1677090) has a missing `/tmp` folder as the cause. Run `strace apt-get update` to see where it is having problems.

Comment: I ran that command @muru

Answer (score 2):

It should also be noted that if you get a `E: Sub-process returned an error code` when running any something like `apt-get remove [pkg]` or get errors when you run `apt-get update` you might want to make sure your `/tmp` directory was not deleted.

Recreating the `/tmp` directory fixed my error as no application could utilize a temporary directory to store temporary files. As referenced by the last reply here `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1677090`.

I made this answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have an incomplete install? If that's the case, you can correct it using `sudo apt-get install -f`. That might solve your issue.

If that doesn't clear up the error when you run `sudo apt-get update` again, you could try running

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

In the past, if dpkg was the subprocess that was giving the error, it would usually show up in the error message, but maybe it is still the source of your issues.

Comment: I get the same error whenever I run anything using apt-get

Answer (score 0):

I had `/tmp` existing but it had unnecessary files/dirs that I removed:

```
rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Executed `sudo apt update` and it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

I use these two commands and it works fine.

```
sudo apt-get remove libappstream3
sudo apt remove libappstream3
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).